# i want to Rerender antd select component default value on app language change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, dropdown, antd

i am facing problem with antd select item. i am generating select item dynamically i am using default value to show checked/preDefined value but my app has mutilple language support so when i change my app language default value not changing. i am attaching screenshoots to give you full understanding [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpXYt.png)

here is my code snippest

```
<StyledSelectLarge
        placeholder={item.settings_help_text}
        defaultValue={preSelectDropDowns(item,syslanguage)}
        onChange={(val) => {
          const current = findSetting(item)
          if(current)
          {
            const payload = {
              id: current.id,
              setting_option_id: val,
            };
            
          const updatedValues = values?.filter((item3) => item3?.id !== current?.id);
          fieldValue('dropdownValues', [...updatedValues, payload])
          }
          touchedValue('dropdownValues', true);
        }}
      >
        {item?.settingOptions?.map((item2) => (
          <StyledSelectLarge.Option
            key={item2?.id}
            value={item2?.id}
            item={item2}
          >
            {item2?.translation?.[0]?.translated_text}
          </StyledSelectLarge.Option>
        ))}
      </StyledSelectLarge>
```

Comment: default value will not change. use `value` prop instead. to know more u can read about controlled and uncontrolled components and how defaultProp works

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace `defaultValue` with `value` and set it inside `onChange` every time

```
function DropDown(props) {
   const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState(preSelectDropDowns(item, syslanguage));

return (
    <StyledSelectLarge
      placeholder={item.settings_help_text}
      value={dropDownValue}
      onChange={val => {
        const current = findSetting(item);
        if (current) {
          const payload = {
            id: current.id,
            setting_option_id: val,
          };

          const updatedValues = values?.filter(item3 => item3?.id !== current?.id);
          fieldValue('dropdownValues', [...updatedValues, payload]);
        }
        touchedValue('dropdownValues', true);
        setDropDownValue(val) // We set the new value here
      }}
    >
      {item?.settingOptions?.map(item2 => (
        <StyledSelectLarge.Option key={item2?.id} value={item2?.id} item={item2}>
          {item2?.translation?.[0]?.translated_text}
        </StyledSelectLarge.Option>
      ))}
    </StyledSelectLarge>
  );
}
```